# How to render a page with arrays and text

Tags: 7

I'm writing a module, which gets called from a MENU_LOCAL_TASK hook.

```
function load_statistics(){
    $page = display_yes_no(10,40);
    return $page;
}
```

the $page is an array used for rendering with Charts API, the problem is that if I do

```
$page .= 'hello';
```

for example, it's displaying "Arrayhello" instead of the graph and hello. How can I render the page the in drupal, to display both text, both charts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
$page['text'] = array('#markup' => 'hello');
```

Or

```
$page = render($page) . 'hello';
```